# Is there a database of plants chemical contents?

Tags: botany

A database where given the name of plants, one can know the molecules it contains.

Comment: Let me know if this helps you. http://bidd.group/CMAUP/

Comment: The Biology.SE community has agreed that **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site as are request for resources (these end up being opinion based). Please [edit] your question to ask as **specific focused biological** question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Under researched questions may be subject to down-voting and closure. Please see the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details.